# SVG: Interpolating three given colors with one linear gradient

Tags: css, svg, linear-gradients

Consider the triangle (p1,p2,p3). Its vertices each have a given colour, that are rendered in the svg image below. I'm now trying to fill the triangle with a linear gradient that "interpolates" the vertices' colours. The colours are of the form hsl(0, 0%, X), with X between 0% and 100%.

So I calculated the path g such that the ratio at which the orthogonal projection of p2 onto g divides g is proportional to the colours' ratio (X2-X1) : (X3-X1). I don't want to go into any more detail here, the maths behind seems fine and has been tested numerically.

In the image below both the triangle and the path g are filled with that same gradient,

```html
<linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0.636269760364935" y1="1.3185582538950014" x2="1.5193472636794865" y2="0.5451509402988475">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="hsl(0, 0%, 5.062685677174472%)"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="hsl(0, 0%, 63.8895619052263%)"></stop>
</linearGradient>
```

g's gradient is looking fine, but not the triangle's gradient as the vertex colours are not correctly interpolated and as I would expect g to match the triangle's fill where they both intersect. Should not every point on the same line that is orthogonal to g have the same colour, or is that not how linear gradients work?

[(Also see image here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()#composition_of_a_linear_gradient)

[image]

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. You would need a 2D gradient to interpolate between three colours in two dimensions, but you can't create a 2D gradient fill with a 1D gradient.

Comment: @r3mainer I don't know what you mean, it's working splendidly?! And as I understand it g is defining a 2d gradient, via perpendicular lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes it's that simple: setting `gradientUnits: "userSpaceOnUse"` on the `linearGradient` does the trick.